# @media query weirdly overwiting another but only in portrait orientation

Tags: responsive-design, device-orientation

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px)and (max-width:480px){
 css instructions
}
```

is overwriting very different instructions in

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:640px) and (orientation:portrait){
 css instructions
}
```

but not the

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:640px) and (orientation:landscape){
 css instructions
}
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with the 480 but I"m being very specific about the device widths so can't see why this would be happening. There's another generic structure css file which holds the main style for all devices but for some reason the one being overwritten isn't reading these but the 320/480 rules. Any advice would be good.

Comment: I could be that they are overlapping, `max-width:480px` and `min-width:480px` maybe the browser is siding with the first rule when it gets an overlap? Why not test something like `(min-width: 320px)and (max-width:479px)` and `(min-width: 480px) and (max-width:640px)`